# Automatic synchronisation not functioning

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an MS access database which i recently created in MSAccess 2010 but is currently being worked on in MS Access 2013. For some strange reason, the automatic synchronisation between the forms is not working forcing me to press F6 to update.   I am not sure if this is an MS Access version issue or something else.

To give an example of my issue, there is a main form which 4 subforms within all linked to a set of rows created in my main form. As soon as the user selects one of the record on the main form, all the other records should update based on the record selected on the main form. Unfortunately, this does not work anymore (strangely it has worked in the past) and I am forced to press F6 which when doing so, all the 4 sub forms within the main form synchronise|update based on the record on the main form which the user selects.

Comment: Without more information, I doubt anyone is going to be able to help

Comment: I have added an example of what i happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit of research and viewing my computure, i performed a Windows update which was overdue by a few weeks. Since then the problem has been resolved.